# Facebook posts by app not showing up publicly

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I am using a WordPress plugin to automatically post a link on a Facebook page whenever I publish a blog post.

For some reason the posting on Facebook only shows up when I look at my FB page, but not publicly.

Does anyone know what's causing this?

How can I have the links show up publicly on the Facebook page?

The plugin I'm using is [Next Scripts: Social Networks Auto Poster Options](http://wordpress.org/plugins/social-networks-auto-poster-facebook-twitter-g/).

Comment: How do you know it's not showing up publicly?

Comment: When I am logged out and visit the page, these posts aren't showing. Same if I log in as someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Facebook app settings there is a switch for making the app public. Even though all my posts say they are public on Facebook, they would not show up for other people if they were published using this app (through the WordPress plugin), unless this switch is set to `Yes`.

[image: making a Facebook app public]